# Is there any way to display a portion of an external web site into my site?

Tags: jquery

Can we do this using jQuery? if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, because the JavaScript security model is specifically designed to stop you fetching data from anywhere other than the server hosting the currently-displayed webpage. There are ways around it, but they involve using server-side scripting (e.g. PHP, ASP.NET, Perl, Ruby etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://url.to.site.com" width="100%" height="300">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Comment: But it shows full site.... I need some portion of site... 
Exp:- i need only news box in yahoo page in my site

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do some screen scraping of the target site for redisplay on your site.  There is no magic bullet using jQuery that will accomplish this task for you.

Have you looked into the Yahoo API?  Perhaps they have something you can use to display news on your site.  There are better ways to accomplish what you are trying to do, such as subscribing to a news feed which is designed specifically for this purpose.  (Eg, a Google Gadget or similar)

Best of luck with your website

Luke Peterson